# What would be the best way to use vue routes?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm a bit new to Vue routes. I have a table in `Home.vue` and each row has a button in order to go to the details. I'll try to explain what I imagine. I want the redirection to open a new screen `Overview` with a sidebar that has 3 options: `Overview`, `Commits` and `Files`. My problem is to understand what should be the parent and what should the child. I'm sure that `Commits` and `Files` are children but should `Overview` be also a child or the parent of `Commits` and `Files`? The row that redirects to details:

```html
<router-link :to="{ 'name': 'details', 'params': { 'tool': tool } }">{{id}}</router-link>
```

The routes that I currently have:

```js
const DetailsChildren = [
    {
        path: 'commits/:tool',
        name: 'commits',
        component: commits
    },
    {
        path: 'files/:tool',
        name: 'files',
        component: files
    }
];

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        }
        {
            path: '/overview/:tool',
            name: 'details',
            component: details,
            children: DetailsChildren
        }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
});
```

And `DetailsChildren` is as follows:

```html
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <sidebar />
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
```

Currently `DetailsChildren` is `Overview`. But I think `DetailsChildren` should be the parent of `Overview`, `Files` and `Commits` and then I need to create another component `Overview`. But then I have two problems. First one is how I load `Overview` when I move from the table to `DetailsChildren`? The second one is that I want the route to be `/overview/:tool`. I'm a bit confused. What would be best way to handle the routes in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is have three children under your `details` route, each with their own absolute path from `/`.

```js
const DetailsChildren = [
    {
        path: '/overview/:tool',
        name: 'overview',
        component: overview
    },
    {
        path: '/commits/:tool',
        name: 'commits',
        component: commits
    },
    {
        path: '/files/:tool',
        name: 'files',
        component: files
    }
];
```

This will create the following path mappings

- `/overview/:tool`

  - Top-level component: `details`
  - Child component: `overview`
- `/commits/:tool`

  - Top-level component: `details`
  - Child component: `commits`
- `/files/:tool`

  - Top-level component: `details`
  - Child component: `files`

See the guide on [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

You may think you can use an empty path for the *overview* route but this would then require the URL to have a trailing slash (ie `/overview/tool/`) and I figured you don't want that.

---

It's also recommended to remove the name from your *details* route and instead, link to the default child route (ie *overview*). Eg

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'overview', params: { tool } }">{{id}}</router-link>
```

Otherwise, the router gets confused about which to display, the parent (empty) or child.

Your sidebar links can simply use the child route names to create their links, eg

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'overview'}">Overview</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'commits'}">Commits</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'files'}">Files</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: Edit loving-dawn-octf3]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm trying to achieve `/overview/tool`, `/commits/tool` and `/files/tool`. That's is my problem.

Comment: @vesii ah, I see. I've updated my answer and have included a demo